# Time difference between Elasticsearch "took" and that calculated manually

Tags: elasticsearch

I can't figure out why is there such a difference between ES time and the query time.

```
var url = "192.168.100.11:9200";
var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');

var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
    host: url
});
var accounts = [];   
var startTime = new Date();
client.search({"index":"test", "type":"testdata1", searchType:"count"}).then(
    function (searchData) {
        var endDate = new Date();
        console.log(" total time : [" + (endDate - startTime) + "]")
        console.log(" ES   >>>>> :" + JSON.stringify(searchData.took));
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(" errr  >>>> :" + err);
    });
```

Output:

> total time : [37]
>
> ES   >>>>> :2

As you can see, es result took shows query was executed in 2 ms, but if I calculate total time taken to run in code , it took 37ms. What took 35ms ?

Comment: Can you formulate a specific question?

Comment: @JonSurrell : As u can see, es result took shows query was executed in 2 ms, but if i calculate total time taken to run in code , it took 37ms. What took 35ms ?

Comment: Network connection time between client and ES server? (e.g. establishing connection and transferring data)

Comment: Try running 2 queries and time each, but make sure the initialization code is only run once. I believe the actual connection is initialized upon first query.

Comment: @KresimirNesek :  I'm running it on my local system. So don't think there is any network time.

Answer (score 21):

According to [this thread](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/query-timing-took-value-and-what-im-measuring/9870/2), the 'took' value measures wall time of query execution in Elasticsearch, which includes queue waiting time but excludes

- serializing the request into JSON on the client
- sending the request over the network
- deserializing the request from JSON on the server
- serializing the response into JSON on the server
- sending the response over the network
- deserializing the response from JSON on the client

Comment: link is broken :(

Comment: follow the link from here https://discuss.elastic.co/t/query-timing-took-value-and-what-im-measuring/9870/2